# Testing asp.net site that uses membership?

Tags: asp.net, testing

I've read some of the topics on stress testing but what options are there for testing a site that uses membership to simulate many concurrent users logging/logged in? I guess one could use/create custom scripts but that would also proliferate the database.

How do some of the 'big boys' do it? BTW maybe stress testing isn't exactly what I'm referring too but like a test suite or anything that would be beneficial..

I can think:

1. Profiling
2. Application Suite testing. Does this exist for web? It seems difficult to do.
3. Stress testing.
4. Performance
5. Hardening/security

Answer (score 1):

It has a steep(ish) learning curve but I use the free web stress tool from Microsoft called [WCat](http://www.iis.net/community/default.aspx?tabid=34&i=1466&g=6).

I recall reading that this is used by the IIS Team to stress test new features - I guess you could call them 'big boys'? You need IIS to be able to run this of course.